# Проблема с кодом - не выводится график

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

У меня есть база данных, в ней множество значений - 4 столбца с названиями : Intensity_without_additives ; Intensity_rotenone+succinate; Intencity_ADP; Intensity_antimycin_A. Я написал код для того, чтобы выполнить анализ по критерию Манна-Уитни между этими столбцами. Но график не выводится. В чем может быть проблема? Мой код снизу

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os


df = pd.read_csv('Intensity.csv')

n_cols = len(df.columns)
for i in range(n_cols):
    for j in range(i+1, n_cols):
        col1, col2 = df.iloc[:,i], df.iloc[:,j] 
        stat, p = mannwhitneyu(col1, col2) 
        print('Comparison between {} and {}: U={}, p-value={}'.format(df.columns[i], df.columns[j], stat, p)) 
        plt.boxplot([col1, col2]) 
        plt.xticks([1,2], [df.columns[i], df.columns[j]])
        plt.ylabel('Intensity')
        plt.title('Comparison between {} and {}'.format(df.columns[i], df.columns[j]))
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Это SO на русском. Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Ты на каждой итерации рисуешь график. Так не надо